# chive on nginx, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Hello there im trying to setup chive on nginx, can someone help me convert htaccess for it ?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php?__chive_rewrite_on=1&%{QUERY_STRING}
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php?__chive_rewrite_on=1&%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you installed chive in a subdirectory "chive" do the following:

```
location /chive/ {
        try_files $uri chive/$uri/ /chive/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

without a subdir:

```
location / {
# ... existing options ... check twice!
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

instead of $args you could use $query_string, according to http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule (It reads: "The same as $args except that this variable is readonly.")

Answer (score 1):

Great project appeared since then
https://github.com/perusio/chive-nginx